# Delete Excel row without unhiding another, VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a fairly simple spreadsheet application with some VBA code that performs simple row inserts and deletes as called by a user. This is a heavily formatted spreadsheet intended for use by people without Excel experience. The code for inserts and deletes is fine.

The sheet uses 15 rows, and every row below this point has been hidden. However, on deleting a complete row, each following row shifts upwards as is standard, leaving a 'new', blank row 15. I would like this behaviour to be overruled and for a blank row to **not** appear.

Might be simple? What would be the option to prevent this behaviour, and if this is impossible are there any tips for grabbing the identity of the 'last visible' row of a sheet so as to hide it away manually?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to adjust this to your needs, but this should work.

```
Sub GetLastVisibleCell()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)

If rng = vbNullString Then rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True


End Sub
```

Comment: @user1731769 -> you probably figured this out, but I just realized I royally mistyped the syntax for hiding a row. I've edited my post with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting a row, clear it instead:

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223828%28v=office.11%29.aspx) gives an example of

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G37").ClearContents
```

Comment: Don't forget you may also want to clear formatting and notes... `.ClearFormats` and `.ClearNotes`, respectively.

Comment: Unfortunately it must be a full row select & delete... each row contains a number of user inputs, and a good deal of formulas that rely on the previous and adjacent rows / columns. I played with the idea of using a pre-set configuration (eg 50 formatted rows) and hiding / unhiding as necessary, but there are no limits to the amount of rows that may be required by a user. Also seems a bit of a messy solution for the sake of getting around something that seems in concept quite simple?

Answer (score 0):

The last visible row can also be returned with an end(xlup) syntax. Assuming your column A has data for each non-empty row.

```
Sub GetLastVisibleCell()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup)
rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True


End Sub
```